# Retain cycle TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to break the retain cycle but couldn’t do it. I just can’t find the source of retain cycle.

```
 class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var refreshHeaderView: PZPullToRefreshView?

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        [unowned self] in //with or without doesn’t make any difference
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None
        tableView.registerClass(CustomViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
        }()

    deinit {
        println("Deinit View")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.frame = view.frame
        if refreshHeaderView == nil {
            println("Adding")

            var view = PZPullToRefreshView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0 - tableView.bounds.size.height / 2, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height / 2 ))
            view.delegate = self
            self.tableView.addSubview(view)
            refreshHeaderView = view
        }
…
…

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PZPullToRefreshDelegate {

// Usual tableview methods
}


// Deinit part of PZPullToRefreshView
    deinit {
        delegate = nil
        activityView = nil
        statusLabel = nil
        arrowImage = nil
        lastUpdatedLabel = nil
        println("Deinit Refresh")
    }
```

When I push this view from navigation controller, I see   "Deinit View” once when the view is loaded. However I don’t get “Deinit Refresh” from refresh controller. It means it retains. If I use below code, I see Deinit Refresh.

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        if self.navigationController?.visibleViewController == self {
            self.refreshHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `PZPullToRefreshView.delegate` strong? If so, there is your retain cycle (VC -> tableView -> refreshView -> VC).

Comment: it was  ```public var delegate: AnyObject?``` inside PZPullToRefreshView class. However changing to weak didn't change anything. I still have to remove from superview otherwise it doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: If something is contained in a superview then clearly there is a strong reference.

Comment: I think I have found the issue. I am using UISplitViewController controller by using http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller example. I tested with iPhone 4S simulator. On iOS 7, everything is working well, deallocation occurs, when I hit the back button. However, on iOS 8, deallocation only occurs, when another detail view controller is pushed. Sample project https://github.com/rnystrom/UISVC-Compatibility-Demo and https://github.com/NatashaTheRobot/UISplitViewControllerDemo put some debug output on deint of detailvc and you can see the behavior.